# How to INCLUDE lib files inside [/Libs/x64/Release] folder in a Git repository

Tags: git, pattern-matching, gitignore

I have a Git repository that contains a **Libs** directory in the root. This directory contains all the compiled .lib files that I want to include in the repository and push to main repo. The structure of **Libs** directory is:

Libs
...--| x64
........--| Release
........--| Debug

The problem is that I am unable to make Git include LIB files inside *Release* and *Debug* folders. I think its because Release and Debug folders are excluded by gitignore:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```

What I tried:

```
!/Libs/*/*.lib
!/Libs/x64/Release/*
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to push build results into the main repository even though someone already explicitly excluded them?

Comment: I have third party libs in these directories that I have compiled separately. I do not want to include the source code of these third-party components in my project so I am only keeping the compiled versions. People checking-out my project won't have to go through the pain of compiling all the third-party stuff as these components are not downloadable in binary form.

Comment: I don't think adding files under x64 is the right thing to do. X64 folder should really be seen as a dump. Instead, I would advise to create a project in your solution dedicated to *copy* the prebuilt downloaded libs into x64/Release and x64/Debug. Typically that would be a project without a Source or Headers group, just a folder containing your prebuilt stuff and a Post-Build Event using a xcopy /y command. And you can use $(SolutionDir)/$(Platform)/$(Configuration) as a target dir.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to use:

```
git add --force Libs
```

In order to add them in spite of the .gitignore.

You can check at any time which .gitignore and which rules of the `.gitignore` is preventing you to consider a particular folder with:

```
git check-ignore -v /path/to/an/element
```

For modifying your `.gitignore` to *not* ignore a particular sub-folder, consider "[.gitignore exclude folder but include specific sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534865/6309)", especially:

> If you exclude `folder/`, then everything under it will always be excluded (even if some later negative exclusion pattern (“unignore”) might match something under `folder/`). (`*`)
>   (`*`: unless certain conditions are met in git 2.?, see below)

For instance, in your case try (git 1.8.2+):

```
Libs/**/*
!Libs/x64/Release/
```

Note that with git 2.9.x/2.10 (mid 2016?), it might be possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded [if there is no wildcard in the path re-included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d589a67eceacd1cc171bbe94906ca7c9a0edd8c5#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R144).

[Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) is trying to add this feature:

- [commit 506d8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/506d8f1b394917c345965fc1762afa66678870c1) for git v2.7.0, reverted in [commit 76b620d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76b620d8166bf4cc7cadbc61f9927799ceea9162) git v2.8.0-rc0
- [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) git v2.8.0-rc0,... reverted(!) in [commit 5cee3493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415) git 2.8.0-rc4.

That means, with git 2.9+, this could have worked:

```
/Libs
!/Libs/x64/Release
```

Comment: "git add --force Libs" worked. Thanks. Is there also a "git ignore --force xxxx"? There is a abc_i.h that never gets ignored even though its in gitignore file.

Comment: @A9S6  `abc_i.h` could never be ignored... if it is already tracked (added and committed) by Git.

Comment: This is auto-generated, not committed by Git. Is it possible to somehow know if this is tracked internally (by mistake maybe)? Can I "untrack" it?

Comment: @A9S6 to untrack, `git reset -- path/to/abc_i.h`

Comment: Sorry, yes it was being tracked by Git. I'll remove it. Thanks again.