# gitignore: Understanding "hello/" vs. "hello/*"

Tags: git, gitignore

`hello/` ignores all folders named "hello" anywhere in my folder structure

`hello/*` only ignores the folder "hello" at the top-level.

Why is this? Please point to a passage in http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore that explains this behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This may seem stange, but this allows us to match directories in multiple ways: files or directories anywhere, directories anywhere, or directories at the top level. This versatility is very useful, and can prevent having a cluttered `.gitignore`.

(FYI, if you have Git 1.8.2+, you can use [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore.html) to help debug this.)

---

If you put `foo`, it will match all files and directories named `foo`.

---

If you put `foo/`, it will only match directories named `foo`.

> If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory. In other words, foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link foo (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in Git).

---

If you add `*`, as in `foo/*`, it is treated as a file glob (relative to the `.gitignore`).

> Otherwise, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a / in the pathname. For example, "Documentation/*.html" matches "Documentation/git.html" but not "Documentation/ppc/ppc.html" or "tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html".

Thus for `foo/*`, Git will ignore all files and directories in the top-level directory `foo`. It will ignore `foo/dir`, `foo/file.txt`, etc. (Technically, this will not ignore `foo` itself, but it will ignore its children. However, since Git does not track directories, it has the same effect.)

FYI, `foo/**` would have the same behavior.

---

**My recommendation:**

If you want to ignore a directory `foo` at the top level, IMO it is most clear to use this rule:

> A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".

So you can write `/foo/`, and it will ignore the directory `foo` at the top-level, but nowhere else.

Comment: I really loved your earlier explanation that you edited out: "The reason for this: This allows users to match directories in three ways: files or directories anywhere, directories anywhere, or directories at the top level." Very nice simple description of the purpose of it all :)

Comment: @stackoverflowuser, I was trying to edit for brevity. I put it back in. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

The relevant passage is:

> Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by [`fnmatch`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fnmatch%203), with:

- '`*`' for the top files
- '`**`' everything inside, with infinite depth

fnmatch is a function which checks whether the string argument matches the pattern argument, which is a shell wildcard pattern.

That is useful when excluding subfolders from an ignore rule, as I mention in "[How to INCLUDE `lib` files inside `[/Libs/x64/Release]` folder in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23821733/6309)"

```
Libs/**/*
!Libs/x64/Release/
```

That ignores everything except `Libs/x64/Release` folder.

In any case, the command **[`git check-ignore -v`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)** is very useful to check which `.gitignore` rule applies for any particular file.